# Evaluation of Markov Decision Process

Tags: r, simulation

I would like to compare the cost of 2 types of interventions using decision trees / state transition / markov models. One of the most frequently cited commercial software for these types of analyses is [Treeage](http://www.treeage.com/shop/treeage-pro-suite/).

Is there a package to perform these analyses in R? Is such analyses feasible in R?

Comment: Maybe the [MDP](https://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/mdp/) package on r-forge?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: [package 'VLMC'](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/VLMC/VLMC.pdf)
and see if it suits your needs.